# Google sheets outer join & difference

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am looking for a piece of advice from someone who is familiar with scripts for google sheets
The application is grading a written test/exam for a cohort of students
There are two tables:

- the first one contains the answers written by students, and
  additionally includes their names (for identification)
- the second one contains the list of all the students in the cohort

Problem 1: join the tables 1 and 2 with outer join. The output is a table that contains all the students from the cohort, and for those who did take the test it contains the answers they provided

Problem 2: create a new tab that contains the difference between the tabs 2 and 1, i.e. the list of all the students that did not take the test

I know how to do this in python/pandas, but I don't have much experience with google sheets, so any help on the implementation would be appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Please consider reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have 3 formulas you could try.

Here is some mockup data that represents what I think you have (for convenience, I've put it on one tab):

[image]

I've added student names in Col A, deliberately not alphabetical. Test results in Cols C and D for those who have taken the test.

The formula to get all students, and their result (if taken) is in cell `F2` (yellow):

`=sort(arrayformula({A2:A,if(A2:A<>"",iferror(vlookup(A2:A,{D:D,C:C},2,false),),)}),1,true)`

It uses:

`ARRAYFORMULA` to cascade the result down the table.

`{D:D,C:C}` is an array that gets column D, then C for the `VLOOKUP` range. You can alter this depending on your source data.

`VLOOKUP` to get the test result based on the list of students.

`A2:A<>""` to do the test as long as there is a student name in Col A.

`IFERROR` to ignore results where student name is not found.

`SORT` to order the results by student name, alphabetically.

The gaps in Col G are obviously those who did not test.

If you want definitive lists of those who did and did not test, then the formulas in `I2` and `L2` give you that. They are basically the formula from `F2` with a `QUERY` wrapped around.

`I2` (green):

`=query(arrayformula({A2:A,if(A2:A<>"",iferror(vlookup(A2:A,{D:D,C:C},2,false),),)}),"where Col2 is not null order by lower(Col1)",0)`

`L2` (red):

`=query(arrayformula({A2:A,if(A2:A<>"",iferror(vlookup(A2:A,{D:D,C:C},2,false),),)}),"select Col1 where Col2 is null and Col1 is not null order by lower(Col1)",0)`

Comment: Since you have mentioned joins I am guessing you are familiar with SQL. Sheets has a QUERY() function modeled after SQL although it is not a full implementation and does not directly support JOINs. If you are interested in trying a QUERY() approach let me know, I have developed a customer function which provides INNER, LEFT, RIGHT and FULL JOINs I would be happy to share with you here.